# Python functional evaluation efficiency

Tags: python

If I do this:

```
x=[(t,some_very_complex_computation(y)) for t in z]
```

Apparently some_very_complex_computation(y) is not dependent on t. So it should be evaluated only once. Is there any way to make Python aware of this, so it won't evaluate some_very_complex_computation(y) for every iteration?

Edit: I really want to do that in one line...

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this in line? That's not sensible at all.

Comment: @NiklasB. No particular reason, just want to reduce the size of the code. One would hope the language would be able to detect "closed" functions and do some automatic optimization :)

Comment: Python functions can have side-effects, so there is no way to do automatic memoization

Comment: @Polymorpher: Pureness analysis is close to impossible in Python, due to its very dynamic nature and imperative style. You might want to look into a functional language like Haskell if you want stuff like that.

Comment: @Wes: Well, there is, it's just very hard to implement. A smart VM could sure detect that `def square(x): return x*x` is pure.

Comment: I mean there is no sane way for the language to implement it.

Comment: @Wes: Yep, I think that's very correct. It's surely not worth the effort.

Comment: @NiklasB. You can only know that `x*x` if pure if you know that someone hasn't done something crazy in the `__mul__` method of `x`.

Comment: @neil: You could make that dependent on the input type (it's always true for immutable builtin types like int, float, string or tuple).

Comment: But yeah, this kind of stuff is what makes these optimization cumbersome and barely useful in languages like Python or Ruby.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually you should follow San4ez's advise and just use a temporary variable here. I will still present a few techniques that might prove useful under certain circumstances:

In general, if you want to bind a name just for a sub-expression (which is usually why you need a temporary variable), you can use a lambda:

```
x = (lambda result=some_very_complex_computation(y): [(t, result) for t in z])()
```

In this particular case, the following is a quite clean and readable solution:

```
x = zip(z, itertools.repeat(some_very_complex_computation(y)))
```

#### A general note about automatic optimizations like these

In a dynamic language like Python, an implementation would have a very hard time to figure out that `some_very_complex_computation` is *referentially transparent*, that is, that it will always return the same result for the same arguments. You might want to look into a functional language like Haskell if you want magic like that.

#### "Explicit" pureness: Memoization

What you *can* do however is make `some_very_complex_computation` explicitly cache its return values for recent arguments:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def some_very_complex_computation(y):
  # ...
```

This is Python 3. In Python 2, you'd have to write the decorator yourself:

```
from functools import wraps

def memoize(f):
  cache = {}
  @wraps(f)
  def memoized(*args):
    if args in cache:
      return cache[args]
    res = cache[args] = f(*args)
    return res
  return memoized

@memoize
some_very_complex_computation(x):
  # ...
```

Comment: Could also be written as: `map(lambda t,result=some_very_complex_computation(y): (t,result), z)`

Comment: @jamylak: Yep, that's true. Well, it's not quite the same in Python 3, where `map` is a generator.

Comment: @jamylak: Actually, I used the lambda version because it's applicable generally (not just for places where `map` can be used). If I were to give a specific solution for this particular problem, I'd rather go with `zip` and `itertools.repeat`, because it's a lot cleaner.

Comment: What an extra hassle! ;) You could use the standard multiplication operator instead (see my answer). But yes... interesting with itertools too!

Comment: Mmm yeah `itertools.repeat` is a much better solution!

Comment: @mac: I don't see what you mean. Your answer just reimplements `functools.lru_cache`, only in a less readable way, without a maximum cache size and without using a decorator (so it has to be replicated for every memoizing function).

Comment: @NiklasB. - I was referring to the one-liner

Comment: @mac: You produce a temporary list there, which is unecessary and might well mean a high memory overhead in the case where `z` is reasonably large. If possible, I usually choose generators over lists. Also, if you do `from itertools import repeat`, `[x] * len(z)` is in fact more verbose and less obvious `repeat(x)` and also requires you to know the size of `z` beforehand, which might not always be possible if `z` is itself a generator.

Comment: @NiklasB. - I agree. Never claimed to be good code. Yet, with the import the other solutions becomes 2 lines, in which case, storing the result in a variable would be a better option, IMO.

Comment: @mac: If one knows Python reasonably well, `itertools` is usually the first thing imported into every module. And yes, clean code matters.

Comment: @Polymorpher: Yep, at least if you want to stick with Python.

Comment: @Raymond: Thanks for the edit, but I actually wanted to have the default value of `maxsize=100`. You're right that I forgot the parantheses, though.

Comment: The solutions from San4ez and @neil are superior in terms of readability, speed, clarity, and use of the most appropriate tool for the job.  In contrast, the answers presented here tend to obfuscate the code by adding unnecessary machinery around the code.  As the author of the lru_cache and the itertools module, I would like to think they offer powerful solutions; however, they are aren't appropriate for the OP's problem.

Comment: @Raymond: Thanks for your opinion. I was just collecting some ideas that might prove useful somewhere in time, because obviously the question is about more than just rewriting this particular line of code, as you might have noticed. Also, please don't refer to yourself as "the author of ... itertools". These kinds of authorative arguments just aren't appropriate for SO, where everyone can just read your answers and build an opinion about you based on that. Moreover, lots of people have contributed to that code.

Comment: @Raymond: By the way, I don't agree that the nested list comprehension with a one-element list is cleaner than the `zip(z, repeat(func(...)))` approach.

Answer (score 4):

No, you should save value in variable

```
result = some_very_complex_computation(y)
x = [(t, result) for t in z]
```

Comment: Ahh... I want to write that in one line :(

Comment: It's better this way, if you had to write it in one line it would not be good code.

Answer (score 3):

I understand the sometimes perverse urge to get everything into one line, but at the same time it is good to keep things readable.  You *may* consider this more readable than the `lambda` version:

```
x=[(t,s) for s in [some_very_complex_calculation(y)] for t in z]
```

However, you are probably better going for the answer by San4ez as being simple, readable (and possibly faster than creating and iterating through a one element list).

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

Move the call out of the list comprehension

or

Use memoization (i.e. when some_very_complex_computation(y) gets called store the result in a dictionary, and if it gets called again with the same value just return the value stored in the dict

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR version**

```
    zip(z, [long_computation(y)] * len(z))
```

**Original answer:**

As a rule of thumb, if you have some computation with a long execution time, it would be a good idea to cache the result directly in the function like this:

```
_cached_results = {}

def computation(v):
    if v in _cached_results:
        return _cached_results[v]
    # otherwise do the computation here...
    _cached_results[v] = result
    return result
```

This would solve your problem too.

**On one-liners**

Doing one-liners for the sake of them is poor coding, yet... if you *really* wanted to do it in one line:

```
>>> def func(v):
...     print 'executing func'
...     return v * 2
... 
>>> z = [1, 2, 3]
>>> zip(z, [func(10)] * len(z))
executing func
[(1, 20), (2, 20), (3, 20)]
```

Answer (score 1):

@San4ez has given traditional, correct, simple, and beautiful answer.

In the spirit of the one-liner though, here's a technique for putting it all in one statement.  The core idea is to use a nested for-loop to pre-evaluate subexpressions:

```
result = [(t, result) for result in [some_very_complex_computation(y)] for t in z]
```

If that blows your mind, you could just use a semicolon to put multiple statements on one line:

```
result = some_very_complex_computation(y); x = [(t, result) for t in z]
```

Comment: Both solutions are presented here already, what's the point of this answer?

Comment: @NiklasB. - The question was about one-liners (poorly formulated, given that the OP seemed then to give up on that requirement). So both the answers that Raymond provided are valid and - as far as I can see skimming through the other answers - unique in their formulation. Certainly it doesn't deserve downvoting.... (+1 from me)

Comment: @mac: The first is the exact solution neil gave and the second is just a rewrite of San4ez initial suggestion, rewritten on one line (which is neither good style nor creative nor does it count as a typical "one-liner"). Also note that OP knows about the semicolon, as can be seen from the initial revision of the question. Also, please don't upvote just for reasons of justice.

Answer (score 0):

It can't know whether the function has side effects and changes from run to run, so you have to move the call out of the list comprehension manually.